# sql search for substring using LIKE vs locate()

Tags: mysql, sql, collation

I'm trying to write a query to find a string that contains a substring. What's the difference between the following two methods?

1. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE names LIKE '%bob%'`
2. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE locate('bob', names)`

I first learned to use LIKE, but I was having "Illegal mix of collations.." error saying that I'm comparing English (latin) and Chinese (big5). While googling methods to fix collation problem I came across locate(), which didn't complain about collations when I tried it. Just wondering if I can keep using locate() or if there's any downsides to it.

Answer (score 1):

To a large extent, it is a matter of taste.

The most important consideration is the `like` is ANSI standard SQL and supported by most (if not all) databases.  `locate` is specific to MySQL, so it is not necessarily portable to other databases.

Some databases optimize the expression `x like 'y%'` to use an index.  MySQL doesn't, so this is not a consideration for you.

Another advantage to `like` is that it supports initial matches (`'y%'`) and final matches (`'%y'`) as well as intermediate matches.  One method for all three.  The equivalent statements using `locate` are more complex.

My preference is to use `like`, especially because of the portability.  However, I am not typically confronted with dealing with different character sets.  You may be better off [learning about collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) in MySQL than in trying to find work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

They are simply not doing the same thing. `LIKE` is an operator which is doing a text matching while `LOCATE` is a function which returns the position of the first occurrence.

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-like-function.php